# Displaying tooltip for a list field

Tags: 2007

I need to show a tooltip for a list field. Since, the field description can be seen by only users with edit permissions, i need to show the description of the field as tooltip for all read-only users of the list.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

I think that jQuery might be a good tool for this.  Are you talking about a List View Web Part (LVWP) or some other type of Web Part?  On a view page or some other page?

Comment: Hello Mr.Anderson,
Thanks for your reply.

My requirement is a typical List in a sharepoint page. We have a urgent requirement like Is it possible to display "field description" to users with read permissions ? when read-only users see the list.

We want to avoid installing any third party tool.

Could you please tell us any other workaround without installing additional s/w ?

Thanks in anticipation.

Saran.

Comment: Take a look at this post from EndUserSharePoint.com which coincidentally was published today. http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2010/05/05/sharepoint-image-preview-on-hover-over-a-hyperlink-field/
It accomplishes a pretty similar thing, albeit with an image instead of text.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Anderson. I had checked the above post but my requirement is little bit different.
I need to show a tooltip for a list "field header" and not list items. Since, the field description can be seen only by users with edit permissions, i need to show the description of the field as tooltip for all read-only users of the list, when user hovers the mouse on list field header.

Comment: Hello Mr.Anderson,
Could you please check and help on this ?

Comment: I'm not sure what else I can add. If you can use jQuery, then you'll need to develop what you need. Since you've said 'We want to avoid installing any third party tool', I'm not sure that jQuery is even an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Anderson's suggestion, you don't need to "install jQuery" on your server. You can use CEWP and Google CDN for jQuery, if possible. Here is a code for adding jQuery in your sharepoint page without having it installed/copied on your server.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
</script>
```

After this, you can add jQuery magic to display the details.